# Opening a new frame with a CommandButton in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I just started programming and I have a question: I want to open a new frame with the command button, it worked on the UserForm but not on the sheet in Excel. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you be more precise what you mean by "open a new frame"? What is the overall purpose of that? What are you trying to do? We need more information (see [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to [edit] and improve your question).

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more precise. I want to make a document on excel for employees, where they have to put the general information about them with some specifications, for example trainee, etc. And this document has to be written on a frame. And the specfications (like the trainee) have to be on "frame2", but unvisble. And I need a shortcut between frame1, the general document and frame2. I was trying to do this with a command button on frame1, so when I click the button, frame2 get visible. But that didnt't worked out.

Comment: Can you show an example in a screenshot please? That would help. I think it is still unclear what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With an ActiveX button:**

1. Insert a button into your sheet from the Developer tab -> Insert -> ActiveX Controls.
2. Double-click on the button and it will take you to the VBA editor, in the Click event of that button.
3. Add the code `UserForm.Show` in the event code where UserForm is the name of your form.

---

**With a form control:**

1. Create a Sub in a module where you call the Show method of your UserForm (or frame as you call it).
2. Then insert a button into your sheet from the Developer tab -> Insert -> Form Controls. It will ask you what macro you want to assign to that button. Choose the Sub from step 1.

   ```
   Sub showForm()

       UserForm1.Show

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think what could be done is to create a kind of shape or button on your worksheet, then, attach a vba script to activate the frame when clicked. It's just the same way on the UserForm only that you are using a shape or button in which you have attached a macro to on your worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

i already did that, and it didn't worked out.